# Achieving more accurate image warping

Tags: python, opencv

could you help me with better paper warping? Right now it looks like this and as you can see it's really bad as many cells are 50% black 50% white. Here's my code if it helps:

```
image = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,warped = cv2.threshold(warped,160,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[image][image]

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want the original paper to be warped instead of black & white format?

Comment: @amras black and white is fine, I want it to be warped so the color value (black or white) could be read properly. as of right now as you can see the image after warping is nowhere near being grid-accurate despite the fact that grey grid is same size as the grid of the labyrinth on paper.

Comment: Ok, it seemed a bit skewed. You can try to deskew it using minAreaRect. In that case it would be more aligned to the grid. Do you need help on this if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @amras I'd be flattered if you could help me a bit with this

Comment: I have tried with skew detection, but the resulted angle is 0.0. Which means no skew it could detect. So it means may be the paper is not straight, hence the lines are bit slanted. Any way I am providing the complete code adding the skew correction part in the answer for your reference.

Comment: use undistorted image and make sure your paper is petfectly planar and the points are highly supixel-accurate

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code adding the skew detection part to your code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
import imutils

image = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
warped = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(warped > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle

print(angle)
(h, w) = warped.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(warped, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

cv2.imshow('Corrected', imutils.resize(rotated, height = 650))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It didn't identify any skew in the warped image. But sometimes it happens that after warping you need to check if there is any skew resulting from not so accurate warping.

Comment: looks better however the image is inverted (blacks are whites and vice versa) and there is no enter and exit from the labyrinth compared to my image

Comment: Oh...that's because I was doing bitwise_not. Corrected the code, please check.